# Design pattern for Data Structure - Double sided Map

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures

I have a data structure problem that I am looking for alternative optimal solutions.

I have diseases and their equivalent tablets that form the cure.

List of Diseases - A, B, C, D, E ..

List of Tablets - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...

Each disease has a specified ORDERED list of tablets that form the cure.

Example:

**A - 1, 3, 7**

**B - 9, 2**

**C - No Tablet can Cure**

**D - 10, 9, 8, 5**

**E - 4**

These are the ordered cures for the diseases.

Problem statements -

1. Given any disease, the Data Structure needs to find the list of tablets that form the cure.
   Example from above:
   Given,

**A - 1, 3, 7**

**C - No Cure.**

2. Given any tablet, the Data Structure needs to find the list of diseases it can cure (with any order).
   Example from above:
   Given,

**9 - B, D**

**4 - E**

**6 - No disease.**

Since the design might be based on the number of tablets and diseases, there can be any number of tablets or diseases, we will for now assume that both are the same number . 10 Tablets and 10 diseases.

The Query patterns are equal for number of tablets and number of diseases.

**Solutions I have thought about:**

I have thought about having 2 maps with lists. 1 Map for Tablets to Diseases it can cure, and 1 Map for Diseases to Tablets it needs to be cured.

Are there any more efficient solutions that can utilise lesser space than 2 Maps and have the same time complexity or be more efficient than traversing the entire list for either of tablet or disease query.

Any other efficient way to solve using Bin Trees, Graphs, Trie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases this kind of requirement would be satisfied with two maps of lists.

This does take a lot of space, though, so if you have a lot of entries (many millions) and memory is short, then you may need a more space-efficient representation.

The first optimization would be to switch to indexes (like a database) instead of having completely separate data structures for each ordering.  If you don't need to update the data structure after it's built, then this can be very simple:

- Make all the (disease, tablet) pairs.  Make sure you always use the same object for the same disease or tablet -- no copies!  If possible, use `int`s to identify the diseases and tablets so you don't have to use objects for them at all.
- Put all the pairs in a list sorted by disease, with the tablets in the proper order within each disease
- Also put them in a second list sorted by tablet

Then you can just do a binary search in either of these lists to find the tablets for a disease, or the disease for a tablet.

If you need to be able to update the data structure, then it gets a lot more complicated -- you'd have to use b+trees or similar for the indexes instead of simple lists.

If the data structure is *still* too big, then instead of making N (disease,tablet) pair objects, you can decompose them into parallel arrays -- one array of N diseases, and one array of the corresponding N tablets.  Each pair is then represented by a single index into both arrays.  These indexes then go into the index lists.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Map as you already thought of: `Map<Tablet, List<Diseases>>` and `Map<Disease, List<Tablet>>`.